# How to split configurations in features to minimize conflicts

Tags: 7, features

I need to put all configurations of a site to features. Some say that it is not a good idea to put all of the site configurations in one big feature. I have also experienced strange behaviour of the features ui when I tried it once.

My question is what kind of rules I need to implement on splitting the configurations between multiple features, to fulfil one important thing: Every small configurations, every new strongarm variable, or field, etc should be completly clear where to put to, to avoid confuse and conflicts in the future.

Comment: THIS is the age old problem. If there was a simple "do it this way and its super easy" ... it'd be in a blog post somewhere and we'd all do it the same way. This type of stuff is a PITA.

Answer (score 0):

What I try to do is to build up features in layers. At the bottom most layer you put all the things that do not depend on anything else in your features, such as contrib modules, site settings and the like.

At each layer you add features that depend on the layer below, trying to avoid cross-dependencies. Each feature should be as standalone as possible apart from its depndencies on lower-level features.

It's difficult to achieve perfection, though, because a new feature may affect things you have already configured. For example if you install the field permissions module for a specific need, that'll add extra settings to fields you have already configured. So that module effectively becomes a dependency of sorts even though logically it isn't.